# What does "interval straddling another interval mean?"

Tags: terminology, interval-arithmetic

I'm looking at the comments in a code base that looks for section of time intervals, and there's this comment saying "If the intervals from the source are straddling the destination interval boundaries, then the interval needs to be split."

Does anyone know what "straddling" means in this context? It seems to be some case of overlapping intervals where the source intervals fully encompasses the destination interval? That's my interpretation but I'm not certain.

Comment: More context is needed, but I would assume that it has something to do with intervals $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ where $a<c<b<d$.  The phrase is not particularly formal.

Comment: I agree with @JMoravitz - but since this is a comment in some code, I'd recommend looking at the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

[Straddle](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20%22straddle%22&source=hp&ei=_NTSY42yOuX0kPIPj8aooAo&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY9LjDBQbfQcOSw2PmaxXQIWXcLCB9g6G&ved=0ahUKEwiNoMPT_OX8AhVlOkQIHQ8jCqQQ4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=define%20%22straddle%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRAzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QM6CAgAELEDEIMBOggIABCABBCxAzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CAguELEDEIMBOgUILhCABDoICC4QgAQQ1AI6DgguEIAEELEDEIMBENQCOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToHCAAQgAQQCjoNCAAQsQMQgwEQRhD5AToNCAAQgAQQsQMQRhD5AToQCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEQRhD5AToKCAAQgAQQRhD5AVAAWKYaYJAcaABwAHgAgAFciAGnCpIBAjE3mAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz):  "sit or stand with one leg on either side of."

Example:  "he turned the chair around and straddled it."

Clearly means one leg on one side, the other leg on the other side.

[image]

Comment: huh, that's different from what JMoravitz and I said... so apparently "straddle" is ambiguous.

Comment: on "either" side of would mean one or the other and not both right, which is what's shown here?

Comment: @24n8:  Read the question:  "an interval straddling *another interval*."  If I'm straddling a log, I certainly have one leg outside *one* side of the log, the other leg outside of the *other* side of the log.  See the dictionary example in my revised solution.